# Trying to create a clock with an LCD

Tags: pi-3b+, lcd

Today I bought an LCD and connected it to my Rasberry pi in order to make a clock and then an alarm. I have programmed the clock and when I run it there are no issues. The problem is that nothing is shown on the LCD. Here is the guide I am following and I am in step 9:

https://howchoo.com/g/zwq2zwixotu/how-to-make-a-raspberry-pi-smart-alarm-clock.
This is the written code:

```py
import I2C_LCD_driver
import time


mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()


while True:
    mylcd.lcd_display_string(time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p'), 1)
    mylcd.lcd_display_string(time.strftime('%a %b %d, 20%y'), 2)
```

The LCD is on port 27.

Additionally when I type `sudo python (filename).py` on the terminal,
it says that the file does not exist

EDIT:This has been solved and the file runs, yet nothing can be seen on the LCD.I also changed the connections from the LCD to the pi and *still* nothing works

Any help would be appreciated. THE LINKS ARE PICS

https://ibb.co/d2XCH86
https://ibb.co/nfT863y
https://ibb.co/j5G91Tc
https://ibb.co/10FHrGQ
https://ibb.co/vXxyY7f
https://ibb.co/NVmmDmk
https://ibb.co/Cvss7Nd

Comment: You do NOT need `sudo` for an I²C device. Is your LCD at 0x27 or 0x3F. Check it with `i2cdetect -y 1`.

Comment: i did, it is on 0X27, also even without using sudo the problem will stay as :         
                                                                                                                              python: can't open file 'testv2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or director

Comment: What does `ls testv2.py` tell you?  In general, "no such file" means exactly that.

Comment: how is that possible, I have the file on my desktop in a folder

Comment: The file needs to be in your current directory, not in some other location. I suspect your current directory is not the desktop. Type`pwd` to find out.

Comment: The try running it with `python /home/pi/Desktop/testv2.py`

Comment: @MichalisVasiliou, why are you asking a question about the LCD when clearly your problem is with running a python script

Comment: what does this mean? `when I run it there are no issues` ... you said that the file is not found

Comment: @jsotola I mean that there were no errors shown on the terminal of the editor

Comment: You are making us guess.  Please edit your question and show exactly what you type and how the system responds.  Preferably by using cut&paste.

Comment: after using pwd and transferring my file to the correct location, it did run but yet nothing was shown on the LCD, just a bright blue. Also nothing can be written on the terminal as the file has not stopped working

Comment: Before people lose patience I suggest you post a clear photo showing the connections between the Pi and the device.  Also add photos of the device itself.  Also confirm that the device is seen with i2cdetect.

Comment: I cannot, all the pictures are larger than 2 mbs

Comment: Put them on one of the free hosting sites and give a link.

Comment: https://ibb.co/d2XCH86
https://ibb.co/nfT863y
https://ibb.co/j5G91Tc
https://ibb.co/10FHrGQ
https://ibb.co/vXxyY7f
https://ibb.co/NVmmDmk
https://ibb.co/Cvss7Nd

Comment: Can anyone else help

Comment: Well guys I am kinda stuck

Comment: Well, you've ignored or discounted the the help many people have offered.  I've lost patience.  I might not be alone.  If you want people to help you. you have to work with us.